# how to use Aria2c RPC server as a daemon?

Tags: daemon, aria2

I wish to run the Aria2c RPC server as a daemon so I can schedule download jobs from my own client using the RPC interface. But I want it to run as a daemon at the same time.

Answer (score 3):

If you need an `aria2c` instance quickly, run the following command:

```
aria2c --enable-rpc --rpc-listen-all
```

This command asks `aria2c` to enable RPC mode (i.e. act as a daemon) and listen to all incoming traffic, which is not ideal for a public-facing server.

You may need to add additional options like [`--rpc-user`](https://aria2.github.io/manual/en/html/aria2c.html#cmdoption-rpc-user) and [`--rpc-passwd`](https://aria2.github.io/manual/en/html/aria2c.html#cmdoption-rpc-passwd) (together), or [`--rpc-secret`](https://aria2.github.io/manual/en/html/aria2c.html#cmdoption-rpc-secret) to run an `aria2c` more securely.